# Is there a way to use slanted shape (different from italics) in text using newtxtext?

Tags: newtx, slanted

I am using newtxtext package and I notice that the slanted shape is the same as the italic shape, is there a way to define the slanted shape different than the italic shape?

Comment: No, as far as I can see, `newTX` provides no slanted shape.

Comment: With `fontspec` (and (Xe|Lua)LaTeX) you could use `FakeItalic` to get a poor's man slanted.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582703/numerals-in-headings-not-slanted-using-newtxtext where a hack and a workaround is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `newtxtext` package doesn't provide slanted type.

It wouldn't be too difficult to produce a full set, but requires patience for creating an extensive set of TFM files. You might file a feature request to the package maintainer.

You can get a “poor person's replacement” by using the TeX Gyre fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{sl}{<-> ptmro7t}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{sl}{<-> ptmbo7t}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sl}{}%
}

\begin{document}

This is \textit{italic} and this is \textsl{slanted}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed to use `ptmro8t`,`ptmbo8t`, and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to make it work with umlauts.

Comment: @tim Yes, those are the internal names in that case.

Comment: @campa `ptm` is the font family chosen by `mathptmx`. Since `newtx` doesn't provide the slanted shape, a different font has to be used.

Comment: Yeah, but in the answer you write "using the TeX Gyre fonts". Or am I wholly misunderstanding something?