# Numerals in headings not slanted using newtxtext

Tags: sectioning, newtx

When using `newtxtext` with `\pagestyle{headings}`, any heading that contain numerals are set without the numerals being slanted, making them clash with the other text. See the image for an example. I am guessing this is a bug with `newtxtext`. I have two questions related questions:

1. Any ideas about how I can/should correct this in my document?
2. Assuming that this is not the intended behavior, what is generally the preferred way to notify the developer about this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{Experiment 1: Chemical Measurement}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's odd, as far as tex is concerned it is `....\T1/ntxtlf/m/sl/10 1
` so a 1 from the 10pt slanted font. It's just not actually slanted. I wonder if that is by design or a bug in the font....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By error or by design the digits in the slanted font are not slanted. TeX has no control over this, all characters are just rectangular boxes as far as TeX can see.

The simplest thing would be to use italic rather than slanted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\pagestyle{headings}
\makeatletter
% \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
\def\@oddhead{{\itshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\showoutput

\section{Experiment 1: Chemical Measurement}

ABC1 \textsl{ABC1} \textit{ABC1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can load `tempora` in place of `newtxtext`.  This is another clone of Times, with slanted digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tempora, newtxmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\section{Experiment 1: Chemical Measurement}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Tempora sample]